# PHP redirect:header but with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

A PHP script I have written currently uses a redirect:header to move you onto the next page.

It is a login form, and *if successful* it takes you to register-succes.php. *if unsuccessful* (things weren't filled in correctly) it stores an error message in a session and reloads you back into register-form.php to try again.

Originally this was working absolutely fine, because all the pages where separate (like register-success.php was it's own page with full HTML).

But I have since changed it so that you stay on the same page and the main div is loaded in via AJAX. This means that using a redirect no longer works.

This, at present is the successful redirect of the form:

```
if(register($email_address, $username, $password) === true){

        // Sends an email
        send_email($email_address);

        $succeeded = true;

        header("Location: register-success.php?username=$username");
        exit;
    }
```

Instead of the simple redirect, how can I have this just reload register-succes.php through AJAX, something like below, but in PHP?

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("login-register-wrapper").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }

xmlhttp.open("GET","register-success.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: Why would you need to redirect, can't you just include the success page in your login script on successful login? That way you only refresh the part of the page that you wanted to refresh and that is kind of why you use ajax in the first place.

Comment: @jereon that sounds like what I want to achieve, I wish to replace the redirect with an AJAX refresh, as I am asking above.

Comment: So instead of the redirect, include the file directly and its contents will be returned in the ajax call (and displayed in `#login-register-wrapper`).

Comment: At present I do not have an AJAX call in the page, I was just using it as an example of what I wished to do. Can you provide a code example using the PHP I have already included? Sorry, I'm looking for advice I can implement as I do not know how to write that in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the redirection in JavaScript by modifying [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location). For example use this JSON as the return value:

```
{
   "Location": "http://example.com"
}
```

And redirect if `Location` is present in the JSON.

Comment: So where would this go in the success statement posted in the OP? It was my understanding that you can't add javascript into PHP? Here is a pastebin of the full registration script http://pastebin.com/CgY6312y

Comment: @Francesca Use `echo json_encode([ 'Location' => 'My-Location' ]);` and then `JSON.parse` the response in JavaScript and `window.location = json.Location`.

Comment: Could you provide an example with the code above? Does the echo statement go in the PHP? Where does the JS go, in a function? Where is the function called?

Comment: @Francesca The `echo` goes where the `header('Location: ...')` is. The JS goes into `onreadystatechange` when `xmlhttp.readyState` is 4 and the status is `200`.

Comment: OK, but at present I don't have the JS on the page. I included it as an example in the page. So how is the AJAX function called?

Comment: @Francesca Read about AJAX yourself, it would be way to long to include how it is working here in the comments and not worth it. There are enough tutorials in the Internet and on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I have used AJAX plenty for simple redirects across my whole site so I am familar with it's use. My question is... You say to put the code above in the redirect success statement, but how is this called? The Javascript needs to be bound to some sort of event or it will just sit dormant on the page. What exactly is triggering the start of the JS with the AJAX script? I see nothing in your example that shows this. I will update the OP with the code you have supplied to explain what isn't working.

Comment: @Francesca You can trigger the AJAX call with whatever you like: A press of a button, submitting a form or whatever you need.

Comment: I have implemented your code. It does not work, in fact it delivers me to a completely blank page. http://marmiteontoast.co.uk/fyp/login-registerv2/register-username-builder.php. Here is a pastebin showing the code you supplied: http://pastebin.com/6MTBZW95

Answer (score 0):

register.php

```
<?php 
 $succeeded = false;
 if(isset($_POST['btn']))
    {
      $username=$_POST['username']; // etc.
      if( $username=="abc"){

            // Sends an email
            //send_email($email_address);

            $succeeded = true;

           // header("Location: register-success.php?username=$username");
           // exit;  
        }
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>PHP Test</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon(s) in the root directory -->

    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"/>         
            <input type="submit" name="btn" value="Register">
        </form>
        <div class="result"></div>

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <?php if($succeeded){ ?>

        <script>
        $.post( "register-success.php?username=<?php echo $username;?>", function( data ) {
          $( ".result" ).html( data );
        });
        </script>

        <?php } ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

register-success.php

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['username']))
{ 
    ?>

<div>
    <h1>Welcome <?php echo $_GET['username'];?></h1>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. For a start it removes most of the code I already have which causes other areas to fail. How can I simply replace the header location: with an AJAX refresh instead?

Comment: The problem is, you can not. See PHP is server side and can not communicate with Javascipt. There ARE some php ajax [libraries](http://www.xajax-project.org/) that you may want to dig in.

Comment: So it's completely impossible to refresh a page that uses AJAX? It has to direct to a new page... Is that what you are saying? There is absolutely NO WAY to make just part of a page update using PHP?

Comment: If you want to update **just a part** of the page, you can do it. I explained this thing only in the second method.

Comment: I have implemented your code as above but it does not work. http://marmiteontoast.co.uk/fyp/login-register/register-username-builder.php

Comment: Okay, I have tested on my pc and its working fine. I have changed my updated my answer with the latest code. Please check it.